# Upgrade Android Studio but AVD manager doesnt work

Tags: android-studio, gradle, daemon

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':path_provider:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Could not find tools.jar. Please check that C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_241 contains a valid JDK installation.

I changed gradle.properties, some files works by changing to org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m

most of the files doesnt work.

please help

regards,

Answer (score 0):

Your jdk path should resemble like this "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241".
The path you've mentioned above is jre.

Also, I think you've recently changed your JAVA_PATH in your system or installed any other software to create JDK path in their installed director, which now conflicts with your old path.

Anyway, go to your Environmental Variables and check for the JAVA_PATH and PATH variables contain the correct jdk path or not.